# Using parallel vectors to form an equation for two variables of a force

Tags: vectors

Say you have two forces (2**i**+3**j**)N and (p**i**+q**j**)N acting on the particle **P**, given that the resultant of the two forces **R**, is parallel to to the vector (-**i**+4**j**). How would you show that 4p +q+11=0?

I know that the resultant force is $(2+p,3+q)$ and know that a parallel vectors have a factor but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: How have you tried?

Comment: I know that the resultant force is (2+pi +3+qj)N and know that a parallel vectors have a factor but I don't know what to do next

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us some evidence that you’ve actually thought about the problem and thought about it yourself. The usual method is: write down an expression for the resultant force ($-t\mathrm i + 4 t \mathrm j$), write down the equation for what the resultant force is equal to (sum of the two forces given), make the two equal, get equations in terms of $\mathrm i$ and $\mathrm j$, eliminate $t$.

Comment: I see, so the i values for the resultant force is equal to -t and the j values for the resultant force is equal to 4t, and now since you have two equations you can get rid of the t and are left with 4p +q+11=0, thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The resultant force is $(2+p)\mathbf{i}+(3+q)\mathbf{j}$ (by adding each term). $(2+p)\mathbf{i}+(3+q)\mathbf{j}$ is parallell to $-\mathbf{i}+4\mathbf{j}$ if you can find a number $s\in\mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$s\left ( (2+p)\mathbf{i}+(3+q)\mathbf{j}\right )=-\mathbf{i}+4\mathbf{j}$$